# Environment variables for MVC app run in VS2019 Mac

Tags: mono, visual-studio-mac, xsp, xsp4

I have an MVC app ported from net framework 4.7 to Mono. It runs but I get this warning during initial startup:

```
WARNING: WebConfigurationManager's LRUcache evictions count reached its max size
Cache Size: 100 (overridable via MONO_ASPNET_WEBCONFIG_CACHESIZE)
```

I can start xsp4 via the CLI and set this env var to increase cache size, but there seems to be no way to configure the XSP run in Visual Studio 2019 for Mac to set environment variables within it's context.

The only way I've found to do it so far is to start VS from CLI as a child process after setting the env var in the context of the shell. However this seems to lead to an unrelated issue with max number of files the app is allowed to keep open. So I would like to figure out how to set vars within the running VS context. Any one know of any way to do this?

Comment: Set the env variable via the startup configuration of the project

Comment: Is that via Run -> Run with -> Custom configuration? I tried setting vars there and they just seem to be ignored.